# Customize domain with my own domain in Azure AD b2b https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management, azure-ad-b2b

Is it possible to Customize token endpoint with my own domain [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant_id%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token)
For example
[https://login.technicalsplash.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.technicalsplash.com/%7Btenant_id%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token) in Azure AD B2B

Answer (score 0):

All of the cloud providers support this -see [this Azure AD guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-custom-domain). It is common to also use subdomains for base URLs, along the following lines, for the Authorization Server, APIs and web apps:

- https://login.example.com
- https://api.example.com
- https://www.example.com

Your OAuth URLs will then be relative to the custom domain name, and the token endpoint will be here. You will no longer need a tenant ID in the URL:

- https://login.example.com/oauth/v2.0/token